# Fastest way to calculate average of datetime rows using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have 122864 row of data. I am storing data in HDF5 file. Using pandas for data processing. For each unique id in record there is a timestamp associated indicating time when user opened an app. I want to get average duration between two hits of app.

```
1283    2015-04-01 08:07:44.131768
1284    2015-04-01 08:08:02.752611
1285    2015-04-01 08:08:02.793380
1286    2015-04-01 08:07:53.910469
1287    2015-04-01 08:08:03.305893
1288    2015-04-01 08:07:44.843050
1289    2015-04-01 08:07:54.767203
1290    2015-04-01 08:08:03.965367
1291    2015-04-01 08:07:45.924854
1292    2015-04-01 08:07:55.408593
1293    2015-04-01 08:07:46.365128

class User(object):

    ''' 
    Properties and function related to each object.

    attributes:

        datetime: a list of hit timestamp for each user object
        deviceid: unique deviceid
    '''

    def __init__(self, User, device_id):
        self.datetime = pd.to_datetime(list(User['datetime']))
        self.deviceid = device_id
        self.avrgtime = 0.0
        avgtime.setdefault(self.deviceid, 1)

    def avg_duration(self):

        '''
        average duration b/w hits for each user.
        '''

        for i,time in enumerate(self.datetime[:-1]):
            self.avrgtime += abs(self.datetime[i+1] - time).total_seconds()
        avgtime[self.deviceid] = self.avrgtime/len(self.datetime)
        pp.pprint(avgtime)
            #avgtime[] = datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

        pass


def eachdevice(gstore):
    count = 0
    for did in list(gstore['data'].drop_duplicates('device_id')['device_id']):

     auser = gstore.select('data', where="device_id == did")
     gamer = User(auser, did) 
     gamer.avg_duration()
     count+=1
     print count



#main workshore
if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        path = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
        with pd.HDFStore('Gamer.h5') as gstore:
            eachdevice(gstore)            

    except IndexError:
        print('\nPass path of the HDF5 file to be analyized...EXITING\n')
```

What I am doing till now is looping through each unique_id and using pandas dataframe select querying datetime for each unique id. This returns datetime object dataframe. I convert this to list and then loop to calculate average difference between two timestamps. 
This approach takes lots of time. Is there any way to do this in using pandas?

Please help.

EDIT: after commenting out all the calculation part i run the code. I think this **auser = gstore.select('data', where="device_id == did")** is taking all the time. How to improve? any alternative or better way?
%timeit result :1 loops, best of 3: 13.3 s per loop for 1000 iterations.

Edit: 
Sample data:

```
                           device_id                    datetime
0   c4be7e55d98914647c51329edc2ab734  2015-03-30 22:00:05.922317
1   05fed9f8e07c3cac457723286d36f621  2015-03-30 22:00:07.895672
2   783faeed9fe35a3f45b521b3a6667a2d  2015-03-30 22:00:05.529631
3   c2022ad838cec35bdb12fc3a6e2cf452  2015-03-30 21:59:59.043905
4   a8a04268ee0c22b26af59e053390cf6f  2015-03-30 22:00:14.248542
5   4e5ed16b44b9cd38c408859d1d241e2d  2015-03-30 22:00:02.391719
6   c0bfd3f9046855ffaaec4d99c367fd8c  2015-03-30 22:00:18.649193
7   95f1182c6e4d601ba0b20f5204168ecb  2015-03-30 22:00:13.629728
8   a85caa7e0a4a7d57e6330c083daff326  2015-03-30 22:00:08.340469
9   46cdbee963814cdb4e6a0ac0049b8fc6  2015-03-30 22:00:23.152820
10  3c8bf70679cd9c6f18aa52d06e0e181d  2015-03-30 22:00:17.619251
11  52bc4e3d9dc373d89ec31effe10e6f30  2015-03-30 22:00:11.591954
12  3477eb25e26b6bff0bfc6c3ee59a5f40  2015-03-30 22:00:25.745083
13  e7bf8ae864f2148831628a6f2e8e406e  2015-03-30 22:00:20.911568
14  a15af8faffd655a3e80f85840bbf3c2a  2015-03-30 22:00:19.017887
15  9d9f71f080c0cf478ec4117e78ff89ee  2015-03-30 22:00:28.435585
16  1633d88738316e3602890499b1f778b1  2015-03-30 22:00:24.108234
17  3362daf99f11541acbf45e70fdaf5f49  2015-03-30 22:00:24.512366
18  96c3c005eaaaa8d6af3f2443ca8f73df  2015-03-30 22:00:29.713550
19  002642b9ed495f84318fcb42557f53e1  2015-03-30 22:00:37.936647
```

Comment: can you read the whole DataFrame via df=pd.read_hdf()?

Comment: yes i can read the whole dataframe.

Comment: Can you supply some data (e.g. df.head(20).to_dict())?

Comment: @Alexander added to the question. there are two more columns for latitude and longitude but i am posting only these two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's create a dummy dataset with 150000 rows similar to yours.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({
...     'device_id': pd.np.random.randint(0, 100, 150000),
...     'datetime': pd.Series(pd.np.random.randint(1429449000, 1429649000, 150000) * 1E9).astype('datetime64[ns]')
... }).sort('datetime')
>>> data.head()
                  datetime  device_id
113719 2015-04-19 13:10:00         34
120323 2015-04-19 13:10:01         22
91342  2015-04-19 13:10:04          9
61170  2015-04-19 13:10:08         27
103748 2015-04-19 13:10:11         65
```

You can use `.groupby` to pre-compute groups. This lets you easily identify all `datetime`s for a given `device_id`.

```
>>> groups = data.groupby('device_id')
>>> data.ix[groups.groups.get(34)].head()   # Get the data for device_id = 34
                  datetime  device_id
113719 2015-04-19 13:10:00         34
105761 2015-04-19 13:11:30         34
85903  2015-04-19 13:18:40         34
36395  2015-04-19 13:19:55         34
108850 2015-04-19 13:20:06         34
```

From here, it's quick enough to identify the average differences.

```
>>> def mean_diff(device_id):
...     return data['datetime'][groups.groups.get(device_id)].diff().mean()
...
>>> mean_diff(34)
Timedelta('0 days 00:02:14.470746')
```

Since the `.groupby` pre-computes the results, every successive lookup is quite fast. This step takes about 2 milliseconds on the 150000 rows.

```
In [68]: %timeit mean_diff(34)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.03 ms per loop
```

You can also compute this on all `device_id` like this:

```
>>> time_diff = groups.apply(lambda df: df.datetime.diff().mean())
>>> time_diff.head()
device_id
0   00:02:12.871504
1   00:02:10.464099
2   00:02:09.550000
3   00:02:15.845003
4   00:02:14.642375
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

This is pretty fast too. For these 150,000 rows, it takes under 50ms. Of course, your mileage may vary.

```
In [79]: %timeit groups.apply(lambda df: df.datetime.diff().mean())
10 loops, best of 3: 46.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: `groups = data.groupby('device_id')
time_diff = groups.apply(lambda data: pd.to_datetime(data.datetime).diff().mean())
pp.pprint(time_diff)`

best of 3: 42.4 s per loop

For one loop: timeit mean_diff('db120223146f426e19c910c7f11d01ad')
1000 loops, best of 3: 984 µs per loop

It is indeed faster than what I was doing earlier. But why in my case it takes 42 sec? (I'm doing pd.to_datetime() coz in my case it is not a datetime object)

Comment: `pd.to_datetime()` is extremely slow. I would strongly advise either not using it, or if you do have to, make sure you run it only once and upfront when you load the data.

Comment: @S_Anand thank you. Is there any blog or tutorials that I can read for data analysis using pandas.

Comment: `data = gstore.data.sort('datetime')
groups = data.groupby('device_id')
time_diff = groups.apply(lambda data: data.datetime.diff().mean())
pp.pprint(time_diff.dropna())`

I don't know why but even after improving this code takes 35 s

Comment: I think I got it. Your example is fast because you are using integers as the key whereas in my case it is a string of 32 characters so even after using a hash table its complexity increases significantly for such a huge amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

To get a dictionary of average difference between Timestamps for unique user IDs

```
device_ids = df.device_id.unique()
device_tdelta = {device: df.loc[df.device_id == device, 'datetime'].diff().mean() 
                         for device in df.device_id.unique()}
```

You then need to convert these timedeltas to seconds:

```
from pandas.tslib import NaT

device_seconds = {device: ts.total_seconds() 
                          if not isinstance(ts, pd.tslib.NaTType) 
                          else NaT 
                          for device, ts in device_tdelta.iteritems()}
```

If the datetime column is in the form of a string, the first need to be converted to Pandas Timestamps.

```
df.datetime = [pd.Timestamp(ts) for ts in df.datetime]
```

Comment: When trying this device_tdelta = {device: df.loc[df.device_id == device, 'datetime'].diff().mean() for device in df.device_id.unique()}


I am getting this error

"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
"

Comment: Added how to convert the 'datetime' string column to Timestamps.  There are many such techniques available on Stack Overflow.